# Why am I getting a "Query was empty" error from this block of code?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a login/register system and when you press login it should say exists...

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';


function user_exists($username){
$username = sanitize($uusername);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());  // Check if query was successful
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // fetch the first row
return ($row[0] > 1);  // If there is one or more users with this name, return true.




}
```

Here is the code that should make the page say "Exists":

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if(user_exists('Zuzima') === true) {
echo 'exists';
}
die();

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true){
    $errors[] = 'You need to a username and password.';
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find that username. Have you registered?';
}
}
?>
```

Please help me I've been working on this for 6 months at the least.

Comment: for one this line: `$username = sanitize($uusername);` $uusername?

Comment: I'm curious... what's this `sanitize()` function look like?  I suspect you are open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: `sanitize` is probably not sufficient to avoid SQL injection bugs. Seeing things like that is never a good sign.

Comment: @tadman I like to MD5 the username field and hash the password. Then use the binary output as the data.

Comment: function sanitize($data) {
 return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

Comment: @ColeJohnson Why would you *ever* MD5 the username? Please don't hash passwords, either. That's not how it's done. [Read about best practices](http://biasedphp.com/php-commandments) and try to adhere to them. It will make your life a lot easier and your programming a lot better.

Comment: @RobbyPool Don't hide what you're doing to escape your data. `mysql_query` is ugly and annoying, that's why you shouldn't be using it in the first place and instead switch to something like [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) which supports parameterized queries. Always make your escaping stupidly **obvious** so there's no chance of a mistake. The cost of missing even a single escape call can be staggering.

Comment: @tadman There's this little thing called sarcasm... I don't MD5 the username, I sanitize it (which MD5 could be used for...) As for the passwords, I know not to hash with no security, I would just use a time-consuming hash like `SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(pass+salt)+salt2)+salt3)`. You could just do client-side with JavaScript `SHA256(SHA256(SHA256(pass)))` as it would take forever. Look at Bitcoin. Breaking ONE SHA256 in 10 minutes with almost 1000 **petaFLOPS**.

Comment: @ColeJohnson MD5 for sanitizing? That doesn't make sense. Do not use a cryptographic hash for storing passwords. Use a proper password crypt function like [BCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt). Don't advocate something like using three salts, and stop making recommendations about things you are severely misinformed about.

Comment: @tadman I never said I was an exper in security and cryptography. (That's what `alt.se.crypt` is for). If you read my first sentance again, I said, I _don't_ use MD5 for sanitizing. I said MD5 _could_ be used for sanitizing provided the input satisfied the condition `charSet^length < 2^32` (where `charSet` is the amount of usable characters [i.e. `[A-Za-z]` would be 52]). I understand hashing a password is not good security, if you are going to hash it _at all_, you might as well use multiple salts and multiple hashings to increase the difficulty of cracking it with brute force.

Comment: If you do know what you're talking about, you're doing a terrible job of communicating it. You specifically said MD5 could be used for sanitizing, and what you've just said makes even less sense than before. Usernames should be validated and escaped, not "sanitized". A database with hashes of usernames is extremely annoying to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$query` is getting assigned a resource handle from `mysql_query`, then you are passing that resource handle in as a string to `mysql_query`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error())
```

Comment: FUNCTION roscapex_site.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Answer (score 2):

> If there is one or more users with this name, return true.

So shouldn't `return ($row[0] > 1);` just be `return ($row[0] >= 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You must alias any aggregates to use in an array.

```
SELECT COUNT (`user_id`)  AS userIdCount ...
```

It would just be easier to return a single column and use the row count to determine if there is a record for your user.

Further, `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. You need to use `PDO` or `mysqli_` with prepared statements.